# T-SQL - Multiple WITH clause and then SUM total

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum, with-statement

I am using T-SQL and aim to use three WITH clauses to collect into my main table query. If I run each WITH query by themselves, I can get the desired results. But when blending it into my main table query, no results show. I reckon my WITH clauses are okay but have played around with my main table query with no desired outcome.
Any help is much appreicated.

```
WITH n1 AS (SELECT m.name AS n1nom, SUM(y.Column1) AS SomeTotal1
FROM Mees m
INNER JOIN Listy y
ON y.m1=m.name
WHERE Yr=2020
GROUP BY m.name)
,
n2 AS (SELECT m.name AS n2nom, SUM(y.Column1) AS SomeTotal2
FROM Mees m
INNER JOIN Listy y
ON y.m2=m.name
WHERE Yr=2020
GROUP BY m.name)
,
n3 AS (SELECT m.name AS n3nom, SUM(y.Column1) AS SomeTotal3
FROM Mees m
INNER JOIN Listy y
ON y.m3=m.name
WHERE Yr=2020
GROUP BY m.name)

SELECT m.name, SUM(n1.sometotal1 + n2.sometotal2 + n3.sometotal3) AS Cool
FROM Mees M
INNER JOIN n1
ON n1.n1nom=m.name
INNER JOIN n2
ON n2.n2nom=m.name
INNER JOIN n3
ON n3.n3nom=m.name
GROUP BY m.name, n1.sometotal1 + n2.sometotal2 + n3.sometotal3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total of `y.Column1` when `m.name` matches any of `y.m1`, `y.m2` and `y.m3` then you need only 1 join and aggregation:

```
SELECT m.name, SUM(y.Column1) AS Total
FROM Mees m
INNER JOIN Listy y
ON m.name IN (y.m1, y.m2, y.m3)
WHERE Yr = 2020
GROUP BY m.name
```

If you want to add `y.Column1` multiple times in case more than 1 of `y.m1`, `y.m2` and `y.m3` match `m.name` then use a `CASE` expression inside `SUM()`:

```
SELECT m.name, 
       SUM(
         ( 
           CASE WHEN m.name = y.m1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN m.name = y.m2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN m.name = y.m3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
         ) * y.Column1
       ) AS Total
FROM Mees m
INNER JOIN Listy y
ON m.name IN (y.m1, y.m2, y.m3)
WHERE Yr = 2020
GROUP BY m.name
```